# GAE NDB with Endpoints Proto Datastore: How to format response fields of reference property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I have parent-child relationships in DataStore model: `Building` entity with reference entity to `Office`. I perform query on `Building` model and I would like to limit fields of `Office` entity in JSON response.
Here is my code:

```
@Building.query_method(collection_fields=('id', 'name', 'office'), path='buildings', name='list')
def List(self, query):
    return query
```

`collection_fields` attribute  works great only to define parent entity fields (Building), but how to limit fields of child entity?

Here is my response message in JSON:

```
  {  id : 5
    name : 'building name'
    office: {
        name: 'office name',
        field1 : 'test',
        field1 : 'test',
        field1 : 'test'
    }
}
```

I would like to remove some fields from `Office` object (i.e field1,field2 etc) to reduce JSON response size.
Define limited`_message_fields_schema` of `Office` object is not good solution, because it works globally. I would like to format only this single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `EndpointsAliasProperty` in the `Building` model, where you can transform `self.office` and use that value in `collection_fields`:

```
@EndpointsAliasProperty
def office_ltd(self):
    limited = doSomethingWith(self.office)
    return limited

@Building.query_method(collection_fields=('id', 'name', 'office_ltd'), 
                       path='buildings', name='list')
def List(self, query):
    return query
```